# How to receive more than one vector in Java?

Tags: java, networking, vector

I am newbie in java, I have a problem in communication client - server, I don't know how to read more than one vector, which I send. I'll appreciate your help :). My code is:
Server:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.io.*;

   public class FileServer {
   private static ObjectOutputStream outStream;

   public static void main (String [] args ) throws IOException {

    // create socket
      ServerSocket servsock = new ServerSocket(2926);
   while (true) {
  System.out.println("Waiting...");


  Socket sock = servsock.accept();
  System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + sock);
  outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
  // sendfile
  File myFile = new File ("D://music.mp3");


  Vector<Integer> send = new Vector<Integer>(); 
  int CRC=0;
  int part=0;
      for(int num=1;num<=(int) myFile.length()/60;num++){
          CRC= (part+num)%3;
          part = num*60;
          send.addElement(num);          
          send.addElement(part);
          send.addElement(CRC);
          outStream.writeObject(send);
          System.out.println(send);
          send.removeElement(num);
          send.removeElement(part);
          send.removeElement(CRC);

          if((myFile.length()<=(num+1)*60)&&(myFile.length()%60!=0)){
              int left = (int) (myFile.length()%60+part);
              int Num=num+1;
              CRC = (left + num)%2;

              send.addElement(Num);
              send.addElement(left);                 
              send.addElement(CRC);
              outStream.writeObject(send);
              System.out.println(send);
              send.removeElement(Num);
              send.removeElement(part);
              send.removeElement(CRC);



  System.out.println("Sending...");

          }
    }
  outStream.close();

  sock.close();

}
}
}
```

Error on server side:

```
[1 60 1]
....
[64367, 3862020, 2]
[64368, 3862047, 0]
Sending...
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
  at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
  at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeClassDesc(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFatalException(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
  at FileServer.main(FileServer.java:61)
```

My client side:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.io.*;

public class FileClient{

private static InetAddress host; 
public static void main (String [] args ) throws ClassNotFoundException,    UnknownHostException, IOException {

  host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
  Socket sock = new Socket(host,2926);
  System.out.println("Connecting...");
  ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());

  long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

  for(int a=1;a<=100;a++){
  System.out.println("seq number of received vector: "+a);

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")   
  Vector <send> response = (Vector<send>)inStream.readObject();
  long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
  System.out.println(response);
  System.out.println("time: "+(end-start));


  }


  sock.close();


}


 }
```

and the error from the client side: (there is no error, but I want to see at least 100 vectors, not 100 times the first one):

```
seq number of received vector: 1
[1, 60, 1]
time: 71
...
seq number of received vector: 100
[1, 60, 1]
time: 79
```

Answer (score 1):

Once an object has been written to an output stream, if you send it a second time, the stream only sends a reference to what has already been sent. So, either create a new Vector each time, or call [reset()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#reset%28%29) on the stream before sending the vector a second time.

Note that ArrayList should be preferred to Vector for years now. You shouldn't use Vector anymore.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know how to use Array List can you shnow me literature?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/. The javadoc should be in your bookmarks, and you should read it every time you need to understand how to use a class. You can also google for "Java collections tutorial" if you need a whole tutorial. An ArrayList has nearly the same methods as a Vector. They are both implementations of the List interface.

Answer (score 0):

For the server side exception. client close the socket after read 100 vectors. while server side still has more vectors to write. So it reported 'java.net.SocketException: Socket closed'

For the client 'repeat problem', you should create a `new` Vector every time in your send loop

Under the hood, Java ObjectOutputStream/InputStream would remeber the 'reference' of every object been serialized, so the object reference map can be reconstruct in the client side. If an object has been serialized and sent before, then just a 'reference' is marked and sent. In you case, a single object is write, the client only receive single object. For more detail, dig into the source code `writeObject`